# How to get a plane to intersect and join/merge with the perpendicular plane?

Tags: modeling, edges, geometry, knife-tool

I'm trying to model my house as a way of learning Blender. I'm having a problem filling in a small hole after following a tutorial about roofs.

It's best demonstrated with a video, but basically I want the extruded edge to 'collide' with the perpendicular edge but no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to snap to the edge it collides with. I'm always left with two unrelated planes which also means I can't make the small trianglar area at the top into it's own face.

Hopefully this question makes sense once you've seen me extruding the roof edge towards the house:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDGNVaY2G-8&feature=youtu.be

Sorry for the youtube link but it seems this StackExchange site doesn't like large GIFs, APNGs or anything else I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You want to stick this edge to this face but this is not a clean topology because your edge will just float, you should first use the knife tool to cut the roof and the left side, in order to add vertices, then fill with faces between the vertices with some <kbd>F</kbd>, and at last delete the inner faces:

[image]

Edit with your current file, as we can see you have floating edges, inner faces, etc:

[image]

What should happen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That worked. Looks like I need to do some cleanup to the model after adding the overhangs, as I can't seem to do a "dissolve faces" to get rid of all the extra bits.  The texture mapping therefore isn't working that well :(

Comment: a bit hard to help without the file itself  ;)

Comment: Here you go, but I don't want to put you out! :)  I'll spend a bit more time on tutorials once I've got a rough enough model to show my architect.  
http://files.staging.x-rm.com/nick/house3.zip

Comment: It's my first model so any feedback would be welcome.

Comment: yes there are a lot of mistakes in your topology like overlapping faces, inner faces, ripped edges, useless vertices, etc, too much to sum in few words  ;)  also try to work with quads even though it's not always necessary and you may not need to worry about that if you stay rather low poly and for architectural objects, but maybe it's better to start with good habits. For the part we are talking about you can see that if you grab a vertex the rest do not follow and you can see inner faces...

Comment: I've edited to give an example

Comment: Thanks! I initially started by importing an STL from Tinkercad so perhaps that's the source of some of the issues.

Comment: But how did you fix it?

Comment: I just did it quickly with the knife tool on the left part in order to create a vertical edge, then merge the right part with the left with some Alt M > Merge, then delete the inner faces, etc

Comment: OK - perhaps I'll just start again with a new model created inside Blender instead of importing what I'd done in Tinkercad (very basic tool I outgrew almost immediately).

Comment: yes Blender has its own way of modeling

Comment: I've created the model from scratch in Blender but not getting very far :)  
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206386/how-to-go-about-modelling-this-roof-shape-in-blender