# How to go about modelling this roof shape in Blender?

Tags: modeling, edges

How to go about modelling this roof shape in Blender?  I started off doing it in Tinkercad and then importing the STL file but that seems to have side effects and doesn't result in a model which is easy to work with. I've been advised to model directly in Blender but having followed some "roof tutorials" I'm struggling to replicate this roof shape (and create the overhangs):

[image]

I guess what I'm trying to do is raise up the vertex A (see below) to create the ridge, but then somehow pull up the vertex B (see below) proportionally so that it creates a planar face?   Or am I simply going about it the wrong way?

[image]

Here is my .blend file:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you need to switch to another way of modeling in Blender (compared to some other 3D softwares), you could start from the shape you show but maybe the best is to start from scratch.

Create a cube, subdivide, pull the top edge:

[image]

Create an additional edge loop on the left:

[image]

Extrude the side walls:

[image]

Cut an horizontal edge:

[image]

Pull the vertex:

[image]

Rework a bit (the knife tool is useful, <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>W</kbd> to cut through, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut perpendicularly, also bevel for the top, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Since latest versions you have the *Extrude Manifold* tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) that allows to work a bit like Sketchup or others, but you often need to give some corrections afterwards to keep a good topology (good doesn't meaning a lot, it all depends on your needs of course):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try now

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I got it modelled in the way you described in only a few minutes.

Comment: Now I just need to texture it and it's pretty much done :) 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206509/how-do-i-make-these-pbr-roof-tiles-not-flat