# Render suddently coming out black in Blender 2.91

Tags: rendering, lighting

I have been working with a blender file for a few hours with no issues. Then all of a sudden, I noticed the the lighting had changed in the Modelling view.   I went to check how it came out in a Render and the render is completely black, with some tiny white dots which seeem randomly placed like stars.

The scene looks like there is a load of ambient lighting still there when I disable the sun effect in the World tab.  Yet despite the extra ambient light (which I don't want) AND the sun clearly shining away in all of the edit views, the render is black and I can't work out why.

I will post a screenshot and my Blend file below:

[image]

Here is my .blend file:
http://files.staging.x-rm.com/nick/house6.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your *Scene* settings, you've chosen your house as *Camera*, select your camera instead. Selecting another object than a camera may be useful sometimes to see what an object is pointing towards (for example select a light and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

[image]

As for the light, it's your world that lights up your object, open a *Shader Editor*, switch to *World* and see, you have a *Sky Texture* plugged into the *Output*.

[image]

If you don't want the world to light up the scene you can unplug its nodes or play with its *Ray Visibility* settings:

[image]

Edit: Additional edge loop in order to sharpen your roof (but *Subdivision Surface* modifier doesn't seem necessary here, it is supposed to round the shape with virtual subdivisions):

[image]

To get a proper displacement for the material called *Pantile*s you need to unable *Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement > Displacement Only*. But as your topology is not very good the *Subdivision Surface* modifier subdivision won't be very good either, you'd better rework the topology a bit so that it is made of regular square faces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That fixed rendering.  Any idea where the extra ambient light is coming from?  And how can I send you a tip / beer money?  :)

Comment: ithe world is lighting up your scene, see my edit  ;)   don't worry for the beer

Comment: Fixed! Looked like the sun was OK but I'd set the "strength" of the actual image too high.

Comment: Do you know what's causing this "sail" at the junction of the walls? Have I missed setting a crease somehow?  https://imgur.com/a/0Jf4gQj

Comment: actually you don't have any light for the moment, you must be talking about the world background strength, and if you decrease it it will darken. For the curve, it's because you've given your roof a Subdivision Surf, I don't why as for the moment it doesn't seem to be necessary. You've created creases in order to sharp the edges, I'm not too familiar with these kind of tools, I prefer to have a clean mesh with additional edge loops if I want to sharp edges, but again here you don't need Subdivision Surface or creases. If you want to keep them for some reason, then add an edge loop (see edit)

Comment: I added the subdivision surface mod because theoretically I'm using a 3D displacement mapped roof tile, however that doesn't seem to be working properly as per my previous question you commented on:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206509/how-do-i-make-these-pbr-roof-tiles-not-flat

Comment: You need to unable Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement > Displacement Only (see my edit)